# How can I use jQuery/javascript to play a full screen video on mobile using the native player from the browser?

Tags: javascript, html, video, mobile, html5-video

I am trying to have my video play on the user's phone when a button is clicked on.  I have tried using a  absolute positioned element, but it has not played.  How can use jQuery or javascript to play the video on click?

**Edit**
The video is just a local video that I have.

```
<video>
   <source url="mysite.com/example.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify what type of element is linked to the video. If it's iframe use allowfullscreen

```
  <iframe src="http://player.example.com" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

If you're using the HTML5 video tag you have to use the requestFullscreen method, according to the [full screen specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/fullscreen/).